# Spark SQL: given a table of users, I would like to create concatenated strings of 100 users at a time. How do I accomplish that?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm building a data pipeline that fetches data from an API endpoint. The endpoint takes a maximum of 100 usernames during each call. As a result, I would like to concatenate the usernames from the table of users I have into strings, where each string is the concatenation of 100 usernames.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT concat_ws(",",collect_list(user_name)) AS users 
FROM <table> 
GROUP BY user_name;
```

I'm having a hard time trying to create the concatenated strings of usernames. Any idea how to do that and get this query to work?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to generate a group identifier for each user so you can group them in 100s.  For this you can take the row number of a row, divide by 100, and then take the floor of that.  The first 100 rows will be group 0, then the next 100 will be group 1, etc.  Something like this:

```
with u as (
    select user_name, floor(row_number() over () / 100) group_id
    from <table>
)
SELECT concat_ws(",",collect_list(user_name)) AS users 
FROM u
GROUP BY group_id
```

EDIT:

I just realized the first group will have only 99 users.  You'll need to subtract one from the row number before dividing by 100.

`floor( (row_number() over () - 1) / 100 ) as group_id`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in the provided query is it has a **[group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) condition on user_name**, so the result of group by is **one username per row**. If you remove the `group by user_name` condition, the collect_list() function should work for you.

if your table only contains one API result, her is the query:

```
SELECT concat_ws(",",collect_list(user_name)) AS users 
FROM <table> ;
```

If your table contains mulitple API result, then you should have a [where](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause use to filter the individual API result. here is the query **template** in that case:

```
SELECT concat_ws(",",collect_list(user_name)) AS users 
FROM <table> 
WHERE [api_call_seq_no]=xxxxxxxxx;
```